# ArcGIS Pro - My point feature class won't display respect the drawing order according to ObjectID field

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, web-service, objectid, draw-order

I'm trying to share a point feature class as a web layer.  When I do the draw order of my points is opposite of what I expected.

It is my understanding that the draw order is based upon ObjectID and will draw the features with FID of 0 last and the last FID will be drawn first.

I want the features to be drawn as they appear in the contents window and I have sorted them, using the Sort Data Management Tool, according to how I want them to be drawn but they draw in the opposite order.

I then reversed my Sort and end up with the same draw order.

How can I get my features to draw in the order I want them to?

[image: Attribute Table]

[image: Contents Window]

[image: Map draw order][image: The help I found]

Comment: Your understanding is flawed. You cannot control draw order, which *at full extent* is **likely** (but not required) to be in physical order 0->N-1, but once the spatial index is used, render order is likely to be in index order (and possibly random within the index page). If there are few enough features, you can make N layers, each with a single feature, but that's about it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I did just that, separated everything into their own feature out of frustration really.  it is bizarre that you cannot control the default draw order within a feature class without using symbol layer drawing tools.  If your conscious while creating features and draw them according to how you want them to draw, you can avoid the headache.

Comment: Further more I'd like to say that I believe the Symbol layer drawing tool should carry over to ArcGIS Online.